# Github Folder structure or layout issue

Tags: github

I have projects save/committed in Github repo, but i have been struggling to understand, why structure/layout of the folders are not display in a way it is save in a local drive. Let's take an example:-

Folder layout/structure in a local drive:-

```
r: src
 c: services
  c:  Basket
   c:  Basket.API
```

Folder layout/structure save in Github repo: -

```
r: src
 c: Services
  c: Basket/Basket.API


Legend: r: root
        c: child
```

Why folders layout are not sync in a way it is in a local drive with Github Repo. Some of folders did save the way i wanted but not all of them. I mean i want it should show the same as it is in local drive like below:-

```
r: src
 c: services
  c: basket
    c: basket.api
```

Any idea??

Comment: If the folder only has one other folder in it, then Github shows them collapsed together.

Comment: If this is the case then it should apply across all the folders in same depth, but it is not the case, some of folders show the way it is in a local drive with same depth, I mean (parent=>child) relationship. There may be some settings or tweak we are missing or it is something to do with Github. I don't know!

Comment: If a folder has more than one folder/file in it, it will show as you expect. It will collapse only when there is exactly one child folder/file.

Comment: Keep in mind there are no folders in git. Only files with pathnames. So what github shows is quite correct and does not matter in the long run.

Comment: Ah! I got your point!!

Answer (score 1):

Github collapses folders when the folder only contains a single folder/file. It does not collapse the folder if there are two or more items in it. For example, if there is a folder A, which has a single folder in it B, then Github would collapse it to A/B. It would work the same if B was a file rather than a folder. If we have a folder A that contains two items, B and C, Github would not collapse the directory structure at all.